# My laptop fan doesn't achieve full speed as it needs to be and shuts down from heat(?) while gaming. I am suspicious about OS fan throttling

Tags: windows-10, laptop, shutdown, fan, cooling

I have a Samsung laptop which is around 7 yrs old. I have a dual boot (legacy) of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. While I am using memtest64 (It is located before the boot), laptop fan can get its full speed without any problem. But as soon as I boot into Windows 10 (or Ubuntu), my fan slows down and gets hardly to speed up. While I am playing games like ETS2 etc. on moderate-low settings, GPU and CPU get very hot and it usually shuts down my computer immediately (thankfully I use SSD).

(I have already renewed thermal paste several times with proper technique and materials.)

I didn't find any PWM settings for my laptop fan, because it is a 3-pin fan. I tried to make Windows power settings to the full performance, used different kinds of manufacturers' software (Intel, MSI, etc.), but they are not useful by any means. I tried almost everything as a basic user could do.

In the end, while I was checking the device manager (in windows 10), I found my fan on there with an ACPI number/address or something like that. But I don't have any access or control over it. How could I control my fans to the full speed? I don't really mind the sound, I just want my machine to work properly.

Specs:

OS: Windows 10 Home edition 64-bit + Ubuntu 16.04

Laptop Model: Samsung NP550-P5C-S04TR

GPU: GeForce GT 650M (2 GB) (425.31)

CPU: i7-3630QM

Memory: 8GB

Comment: This certainly doesn't solve your problem as you ask it but I myself bought a stand like [this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/proHT-15-6-in-Notebook-Laptop-Cooling-Fan-Stand-03030/304707887) to cool my old laptop off.

Comment: I've already tried several different thermal stands, but they are useless in my condition.

Comment: At 7 yo, I have to think that there is significant dust in the ventilation. Try blowing it out with compressed air and using a vacuum to clean up

Comment: I've already cleaned it up several times, too. Look, if you can read it, my fan is working perfectly in boot conditions, it's not a hardware problem. The main problem is, it's not working in Windows 10 or Ubuntu 16.04. So my main problem is a software problem.

Answer (score 0):

to change laptop fan speed you can follow this guide:
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZhf-vIlLoY

But you should be aware that messing up with the internal controller can cause many problem on your computer.
Laptop are not recommended for gaming because they have inefficient cooling system.
they use centrifuge type fans that are connected by copper pipe to the cpu which is very ineffective  even if you change thermal paste or remove the dust in the filter.
You should consider to build a desktop system for gaming even a mid rate one will perform better.
Hope it help.

Comment: I also used SpeedFan, Hwinfo, NoteBook FanControl and several options. But it didn't work out. While I was looking for it, I've found how to access to the ACPI database(?) in here https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/wiki/Analyze-your-notebook%27s-DSDT , but I couldn't found out which registry values my laptop's fan is holding. So, I am stuck at here right now.